# Including markup for React Native Component Tags inside a Text Element

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to include code examples in a style guide for a React Native project and have had trouble finding a way to include the tags without React Native trying to render them itself.

I was hoping to simulate something sort of like Stackoverflow does with it's codeblocks like this:

```
 // Example code for implementing custom button:
 <CustomButton
   color="primary"
   title="Submit"
 />
```

So my code that breaks looks something like this:

```
<View>
  <Text>
    // Example code for implementing custom button:
    <CustomButton
      color="primary"
      title="Submit"
    />
  </Text>
</View>
```

Because React Native tries to render the Button and throws errors.

Is there something similar to HTML's `<code>` tag inside of React Native or some custom way of achieving the same functionality?

Comment: Have you tried using a JS expression? So put something like `{    '<CustomButton
      color="primary"
      title="Submit"
    />'}` inside the Text tags

Comment: Nice, that worked awesome. I tried this but must have just been using only double or single brackets and not noticed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work is storing the text as a string in some variable and just rendering that inside the container:

```
let codeBlock = "<CustButton \n\tcolor=\"primary\" \n\ttitle=\"Placeholder\" \n/>"

<View>
  <Text>
    // Example code for implementing custom button:
    {codeBlock}
  </Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

with [jsx-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-to-string), you can

```js
<View>
    <Text>
        {jsxToString(
            <CustomButton color="primary" title="Submit" />
        )}
  </Text>
</View>
```

This way you can reuse your jsx object easily instead of convert to string manually.